# Dim whole screen in asp:UpdateProgress

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm creating an ASpP.Net web page. Because it has to load a huge amount of date which can take up to 60 seconds, I'd like to inform the user that is may take a while.I'd like to dim the whole screen down a bit and write "Loading, please wait" on top of that. To do that, I created a div inside the `<UpdateProgress>`, made it black and semi-transparent and added the css atrributes `position: fixed; width:100%; height: 100%;`.

The problem is that ASP.net converts the whole `<UpdateProgress>` into a div which wraps my customized div. That results in my div only filling the parent div.

So my question is: how can I modify the css style of `<UpdateProgress>`? (Unlike other ASP.net elements, if doesn't seem to have a `CssClass` property)

Comment: Define your DIV style as position:absolute ? That should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your `UpdateProgress`, this will allow you to assign it a static ID so .NET won't autogenerate it, like this:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Now you have a static ID you can use it to apply your CSS styles directly to the `div` generated by `UpdateProgress`

```
#UpdateProgress {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```